# Lstlisting caption: Number style

Tags: tables, formatting, listings, numbering, captions

When adding a listing to my document, the caption style differs from figures or tables.
E.g.:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,captionpos=b,caption=This is foo,label=src:foo]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

results in: "Listing (1.1) This is foo"

Notice that the number is surrounded by ( ... )

When using Figures,
e.g.

```
\begin{figure{}[tb]
...
\caption{This is bar}
\end{figure}
```

The output is: "Figure 1.2: This is bar"

I want the caption style of figures also for my listings, i.e., "Listing 1.1: This is foo"

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Since that is not the standard behaviour, we will need to see a MWE (a simple, complete and minimal document) allowing us to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question and include there this MWE.

Comment: Thx, creating a MWE solved the problem:
The listing was inside a subfigure - thx for the help!

Comment: I see.Glad you found the cause of the problem. Usually buiding a MWE has precisely this effect: you can discover the problem and find a solution. Most probably, we will close this question then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized and won't probably help other users.